# Problem with tensorflow c++ compiler when I compile python ./configure

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I directly use developer cmd VS2019 for build.

````
WARNING: Running Bazel server needs to be killed, because the startup options are different.
FATAL: Command line too long (34754 > 32768): C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" "--
C:\tensorflow1\models\research\slim\bin;C:\tensorflow1\```
````

Comment: `Command line are to long` everything is in the warning message. Stop the server manually, or reinstall it in a shorter path.

Comment: so, does it mean, it actually load every path available? I already tried it in different version of TF but the result is the same.
I used ctrl+c and ctrl+pausebreak but din't do any good? as for reinstalling in shorter path I don't have an idea of it. how can it be done?